# Google Adsense in Flash

Tags: flash, adsense

Is there a way?

I know its not possible to copy and paste the javascript code into Flash, because Flash won't do anything about it (or cause an error).

But I do know the Google Adsense code generates an iFrame to show the ad. So I was thinking if I were to grab the iFrame source (the src attribute) and load that html page into Flash... maybe?

So I guess my question would be is it possible to have Flash load an HTML page?

I know there is MochiAds, but I would like to get a little bit more % of the $ :)

Answer (score 2):

This will do it with a textfield, set it to dynamic. Then click Render Text as HTML in properties or set the .html property to true. Then use Loadvars to load the html file and assign the variable into the textfield.htmlText property.

```
loadText = new LoadVars();
loadText.onLoad = function()
{
    _root.helpText_txt.html = true;
    _root.helpText_txt.htmlText = this.testText;
}
loadText.load("text.htm");
```